# Does taking a shower when dehydrated increase body weight?

Tags: water, sport, weight-loss, dermatology

For sports (such as wrestling, MMA, judo, etc) where the competition is divided into weight divisions, it's common to drop cut 10+ lbs of water weight hours before weigh ins and then rehydrate right after. It's a popular, and seemingly unproven, claim that when you are severely dehydrated, you should not take a shower because your skin can absorb some of the water, thereby increasing your bodyweight.

So the question is... can your skin, in fact, absorb water when severely dehydrated to a degree that it would affect your body weight by more than a quarter pound?